# Using param aliases in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I've created a renaming script that includes aliases for variables that I would like to define as parameters when I call the script. If I define the variables in the script the traditional way (`$variable = 'defined'`) the script renames the appropriate file correctly. I think I am misunderstanding the param portion.

Here's the script:

```
#retrieve the name from the text file
$name = Get-Content "C:\name.txt"

#identify the .jpg that needs to be renamed based on naming (Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss")
$fileName = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"

param (
    
[Parameter(<#mandatory=$true#>)]
[alias("v")]
[string] $variant,
[Parameter(<#mandatory=$true#>)]
[alias("pc")]
[string] $processClass
)

#identify new name set up and identify the file to address (oldname) then rename it
$newname  = "D:\Output\$name" + "." + $variant + ".PC_" + $processClass + ".jpg"
$oldName = gci "D:\Output\" -Filter *.jpg | Where-Object {$_.name -like "*$fileName*"}
    rename-item $oldName.FullName $newname -Force
```

Then I will call the script with the parameters applied like this:

```
powershell.exe -File C:\Rename.ps1  -v "XXX" -pc "YYY"
```

However at this point, the `$oldName` file is only partially renamed, missing the `$variant` and `$processClass` portion and I get a PowerShell error:

> param : The term 'param' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
> function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
> name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
> try again.

It seems im not properly defining the parameters or I have just misunderstood how this part works, I've not tried this before.

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: you are NOT allowed to put other code BEFORE the `param` block. [*grin*]

Comment: Correct^ `Param` block is always at the top.

Comment: oh, finicky is it? This worked, thanks so much. Please submit as an answer and I will give the due credit.

Comment: @Garrett - done! [*grin*] please let me know if you think it needs improvement. i think it _does need such_ ... but can't think of how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your problem is the placement of code *before* the `Param()` block. [*grin*] simply move all that pre-`Param()` code to *after* the `Param()` block and things will work.

you may also want to consider adding `[CmdletBinding()]` just before the `Param()` to make it a full "advanced function".